# Geforce Gtx1070 - Supported or not?

Tags: gpu, hardware, compatibility

I'm thinking of buying a new computer for 3d modelling. 
I read that there are/were problems with geforce gtx1070. 
is this still a thing or is it fixed by now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Blender 2.78 and above versions all have support for Pascal architecture (10 series)

Comment: wow that was super fast :D
thanks! 
so i should be good. 
can´t wait to try blender with a `fast`computer and not my super old netbook !

Comment: @Janvan yea I've got a 1060 6GB and its a blessing. Have fun with that 1070.

Comment: nice, now im even more excited!
thanks a lot

Comment: A lot of the recent issues have been driver related, which should be fixed fairly soon after release. I'd recommend not updating drivers for a few weeks after release just to be sure

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ So i just did the stupid thing of updating all drivers on my brandnew pc, i guess i got in kind of euphoria and didn´t really thought about it.
now i get a CUDA ERROR, when tyring to render via Gpu.
is there a way to delete the new driver version?
im kind of lost here :D

Comment: @Janvan Sorry it took a while to respond. What exactly does the error message say?